# Azure DevOps proxy for Git

Tags: azure-devops

Does Azure DevOps 2019 Proxy server (formerly TFS proxy server) support Git repositories? The documentation only mentions TFVC repositories, and it works great, but we are not sure if Git repositories can be configured to use Azure DevOps (TFS) proxy (not to confuse with regular Web proxy). Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Azure DevOps (or TFS) Proxy was designed to support Team Foundation Version Control while TFS did not support GIT in earlier versions. The documentation does not contain any information for GIT, it contains only for TFVC: [Configure Team Foundation version control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/install-proxy-setup-remote?view=azure-devops-2020#configure-team-foundation-version-control).

Consider using Git Virtual File System: https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit